# How to add a simple footer to web page using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to add a simple footer to web page using **bootstrap** ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS). https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
    <p class="pull-left">&copy; your copy  <?= date('Y') ?></p>
    <p class="pull-right"><?php Your motto ?></p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thanks :)